# Generate dynamic html table in Javascript not works in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

I have created a table in div element in Javascript with some rows and columns

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById('divExcelData');
var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
  tableElement.border = "1";

  for (var r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
      var rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var c = 1; c <= 2; c++) {

          var colElement = document.createElement('td');
          colElement.setAttribute("style", "width:80px; height:20px; border:1px solid Black;");              
          var divElement = document.createElement('div');

          divElement.id = r + '_' + c;
          divElement.contentEditable = "true";
          divElement.style.width = "100%";
          divElement.style.height = "100%";       
          colElement.appendChild(divElement);
          rowElement.appendChild(colElement);
          }
          parentElement.appendChild(tableElement);
    }
```

but problem is when I debug the page from Internet Explorer(9) developer tools it shows inner html of table element as...

```
<TABLE border=1>
<TR>\r\n
<TD>\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=1_1 contentEditable=true></DIV>
</TD>\r\n
<TD>\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=1_2 contentEditable=true></DIV></TD>
</TR>
\r\n
<TR>\r\n
<TD>\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=2_1 contentEditable=true></DIV>
</TD>
\r\n
<TD>
\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=2_2 contentEditable=true></DIV>
</TD>
</TR>
\r\n
<TR>
\r\n
<TD>
\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=3_1 contentEditable=true></DIV>
</TD>
\r\n
<TD>
\r\n
<DIV style=\"WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%\" id=3_2 contentEditable=true>
</DIV>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

I don't know why \r\n is added in HTML and also style element contains (\") instead of ("). That's why the page shows nothing. This code works well in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I've just discovered that document.createElement("div").outerHTML = "\r\n<div></div>" in IE for some pages.  Why?